# Objective C NSNumbers in if statements

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, nsnumber

Hi I am retrieving an NSNumber value from an array (a rating e.g. 4.3) and am then need to test this value to then assign star rating images.

However when I write the if statement, I am getting errors "Expected Expression"

Here is the code:

```
if (rating >=1 && <2) {
        return [UIImage imageNamed:@"1starimage"];
    }else if (rating  >=2 && <3){
        return [UIImage imageNamed:@"2starimage"];
    }
```

Thanks for any explanation on how I can do this without causing errors.

Comment: `rating.floatValue >=1 && rating.floatValue <2` if `rating` is a `NSNumber`. Else, you need to put the var each time for each test (for >= and for < 2), nothing says that's the same var that's tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an `if` statement with multiple test values, you have to provide the full expression for each comparison.

So in your case, you must do as follows:

```
if ([rating floatValue] >= 1 && [rating floatValue] < 2) {
    return [UIImage imageNamed:@"1starimage"];
} else if ([rating floatValue]  >= 2 && [rating floatValue] < 3){
    return [UIImage imageNamed:@"2starimage"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Left side of second comparison is missing 
It should be`if (rating.floatValue >=1 && rating.floatValue<2)`